# Using grid-template-areas without defining class for each area

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to use grid-template css like this:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      'a b c d'
      'e e e f'
      'g g h h'
      'g g i j'
      'm l l o'
      'n k p o'
      'q q q o'
  ;
  grid-gap:5px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: white;
}

/* looking for a way to trim this part of css */
.a {grid-area:a}
.b {grid-area:b}
.c {grid-area:c}
.d {grid-area:d}
.e {grid-area:e}
.f {grid-area:f}
.g {grid-area:g}
.h {grid-area:h}
.i {grid-area:i}
.j {grid-area:j}
.k {grid-area:k}
.l {grid-area:l}
.m {grid-area:m}
.n {grid-area:n}
.o {grid-area:o}
.p {grid-area:p}
.q {grid-area:q}
/* <-- */
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item a">a </div>
    <div class="item b">b </div>
    <div class="item c">c </div>
    <div class="item d">d </div>
    <div class="item e">e </div>
    <div class="item f">f </div>
    <div class="item g">g </div>
    <div class="item h">h </div>
    <div class="item i">i </div>
    <div class="item j">j </div>
    <div class="item k">k </div>
    <div class="item l">l </div>
    <div class="item m">m </div>
    <div class="item n">n </div>
    <div class="item o">o </div>
    <div class="item p">p </div>
    <div class="item q">q </div>
</div>
```

It feels like declaring a css class for each area is redundant. Is there a way to make the grid area defaults to the class name? Like in my example: .a == grid-area:a without the need to explicitly declare each css class?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The marked duplicate is a totally different question. I had this question today and ended up here and the above comment seems to be the answer, this question should be open and not point to a misleading duplicate

Comment: @TJ the duplicate is an *exact* duplicate. The same code is used and we have the same goal. And the answer isn't simply *No*. The answer is *actually you cannot* but it can be possible in the future using `attr` which is explained in the duplicate where there is also another alternative. Even if we consider the fact the answer will be *no* then it should belong to the duplicate target but it's already trivial from the question/answer there that the answer is actually *no*.